# How to transform this array in php?

Tags: php

```
$array1 = [
  2019 => [
    Biomasse => [summe => 32113]
    Solar => [summe => 21321]
  ]
  2020 => [
    Biomasse => [summe => 3123113]
    Solar => [summe => 21421321]
  ]
  2021 => [
    Biomasse => [summe => 2122]
    Solar => [summe => 1233]
  ]
]
```

I want to sort the array by the "biomasse" and "solar". For example:

```
$array2 = [
    Biomasse => [summe => 32113,3123113, 2122]
    Solar => [summe => 21321, 21421321, 1233]
]
```

The "summe" should be sorted by the years.

Comment: That is a **little more than just a sort** You are also asking to transform the array

Comment: And your output example does not appear to make much sense in the first place. Why should the first of those values get the key `summe`, and then the following simply numeric keys …?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We don’t want to answer plain “how to” questions for people all day, writing the code for them. You are supposed to present your own _attempt_ at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions regarding the question here, and having my doubts about the structure of the data provided, but...

Assuming that this is the result that you want, having Biomasse and Solar sorted by Year.

```
$array2 = [
    Biomasse => [ valueOf2019, valueOf2020 , valueOf2021 ]
    Solar => [ valueOf2019, valueOf2020 , valueOf2021 ]
]
```

Then you should first do a [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), then a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and then you can simply add the values to a new array.

Example;

```php
$array1 = Array(
  "2019" => Array(
    "Biomasse" => Array( 32113 ),
    "Solar" => Array( 21321 )
  ),
  "2020" => Array(
    "Biomasse" => Array( 3123113 ),
    "Solar" => Array( 21421321 )
  ),
  "2021" => Array(
    "Biomasse" => Array( 2122 ),
    "Solar" => Array( 1233 )
  )
);

ksort( $array1 );

$array2 = Array(
    "Biomasse" => Array(),
    "Solar" => Array()
);

foreach($array1 as $year ){
        $array2["Biomasse"][] = $year["Biomasse"][0];
        $array2["Solar"][] = $year["Solar"][0];
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $array2 );
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$output = [];

foreach ($array1 as $array1Row) {
    foreach ($array1Row as $key => $summeArray) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $output)) {
            $output[$key]['summe'] = [];
        }
        $output[$key]['summe'][] = $summeArray['summe'];
    }
}

foreach ($output as $key => $sumArray) {
    sort($output[$key]['summe']);
}
```